# How to get value from form input type=radio?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

```
<input type="radio" value="0" name="type" checked="yes" />
<label>Type 0</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="type" />
<label>Type 1</label>
```

and js:

```
var type = this.type.value;
alert(type);
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: `yes` is not a valid value for the `checked` attribute, I think you mean `checked`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In what context does that JS code run? If `this` is the radio button in question then `this.value` will return the value.

If your question is "How do I get the value of the currently selected radio button in the 'type' group?" then you may need to do something like this:

```
function getCheckedRadioValue(radioGroupName) {
   var rads = document.getElementsByName(radioGroupName),
       i;
   for (i=0; i < rads.length; i++)
      if (rads[i].checked)
          return rads[i].value;
   return null; // or undefined, or your preferred default for none checked
}

var checkedValue = getCheckedRadioValue("type");
```

(It would be easier with [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) or [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), but not all browsers support them.)

Answer (score 2):

Just use selectors.

With jquery

```
$("input[name=type]:checked").val();
```

Or without jquery:

```
document.querySelector("input[name=type]:checked").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `this.value` instead of `this.type.value`.

`this.value` will select the value associated with the `value` attribute of the input. (That's a mouthful).

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery you can do like this

```
   $(function() {
        $(".rad").click(
        function() {
             alert(this.value);
        });
    });
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzFW/4/)

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but that fiddle doesn't even work. You need either `$(this).val()` or, better, `this.value`, but either way your code needs jQuery - of which there is no mention in the question.